# Retrofit2 call with okHttp fails with "client == null"

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit2, okhttp

I am working on an Android App with Retrofit2 and OkHttp and it´s the first time that I use both frameworks. The Retrofit Request fails with the error message " java.lang.NullPointerException: client == null" in Line 138 of my Android Service class:

```
 static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(PalletteApi.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttp)
            .build();
```

the okHttp Instance that I am passing as a parameter to the Retrofit client call is null there, and I don´t know why. I know it has to do with passing of the context in this Service class; however, the right application of the Android Context in this Service class is unclear to me.
Therefore, any hints or help would be very much appreciated.

This is the Service class:

```
package com.examplexxx_app;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.UserHandle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import okhttp3.Credentials;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import static com.example.xxx.MainDetailActivity.TAG;

public class RestClient extends Context {

    public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    public RecyclerviewAdapter adapterRecyclerView;
    private static Context mContext;
    private static RestClient instance;
    public MediaPlayer mp;
    public String basic = Credentials.basic("xxx", "xxx");

    Context context = this;

    public RestClient (Context mContext)  {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.adapterRecyclerView = adapterRecyclerView;
    }

    public SSLContext getSSLConfig(RestClient restClient) throws CertificateException, IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

        // Loading CAs from an InputStream
        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        Certificate ca;
       
        try (InputStream cert = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.android_selfsigned)) {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert);
        }

        // Creating a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore   = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore.
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Creating an SSLSocketFactory that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return sslContext;
    }

   static OkHttpClient okHttp;

    {
        try {
            okHttp = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(getSSLConfig(this).getSocketFactory())
                     .build();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(PalletteApi.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttp)
            .build();


    public static void getPalettes(Context context, SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter adapter,
                                   String basic) {

        //creating the paletteApi interface
        PalletteApi palletteApi = retrofit.create(PalletteApi.class);

        //making the call object
        Call<List<Pallette>> call = palletteApi.getPallettes(basic);

        //call.execute();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Pallette>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Pallette>> call, @NonNull
                    Response<List<Pallette>> response) {

                if(response.isSuccess()) {
                    List<Pallette> postList = response.body();
                    adapter.setPostList(postList);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    int statusCode  = response.code();
                    Toast.makeText(context, statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Pallette>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void putItemOnPallet(Context context,
                                   String basic, String palNo, String bookingType, String itemNo,
                                       String ean, String quantity, String source, Date date) {

        ItemsApi itemsApi = retrofit.create(ItemsApi.class);
        //making the call objects
        Call<List<Items>> call = itemsApi.putItems(basic,bookingType,palNo, itemNo,
                ean, quantity, source, date);

     //call.execute();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Items>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Items>> call, @NonNull
                    Response<List<Items>> response) {

                if(response.isSuccess()) {
                    List<Items> postList = response.body();

                }
                else {
                    int statusCode  = response.code();
                    Log.d(TAG, "statusCode" + statusCode);
                    //Toast.makeText(context, statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Items>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "t.getMessage" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void removeItemFromPallet(Context context,
                                            String basic, String bookingType, String palNo, String itemNo, String ean,
                                            String quantity, String packageCode, String target, Date date) {

        ItemsApi itemsApi = retrofit.create(ItemsApi.class);
        //making the call objects
        Call<List<Items>> call = (Call<List<Items>>) itemsApi.removeItems(basic,palNo,bookingType, itemNo, ean,
                quantity,packageCode,target,date);

        //call.execute();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Items>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Items>> call, @NonNull
                    Response<List<Items>> response) {

                if(response.isSuccess()) {
                    List<Items> postList = response.body();

                }
                else {
                    int statusCode  = response.code();
                    Log.d(TAG, "statusCode" + statusCode);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Items>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "t.getMessage" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void getItems(Context context, RecyclerviewAdapter adapter, String basic) {

        //creating the paletteApi interface
        ItemApi itemApi = retrofit.create(ItemApi.class);

        //making the call object
        Call<Item> call = (Call<Item>) itemApi.getItems(basic);

        //call.execute();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Item>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Item> call, @NonNull Response<Item> response) {

                if(response.isSuccess()) {

                    DatabaseHandler itemsManager = new DatabaseHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
                    itemsManager.addItem(response.body());
                    //adapter.setItemList(itemList);
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    int statusCode  = response.code();
                    Toast.makeText(context, statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Item> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void checkItemsAgainstDatabase(Context context, String ean, String basic,Context mContext) {

        //creating the paletteApi interface
        ItemApi itemApi = retrofit.create(ItemApi.class);

        //making the call object
        Call<Item> call = itemApi.checkItem(basic, ean);

        //call.execute();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Item>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Item> call, @NonNull Response<Item> response) {

                if(response.isSuccess()) {
                    //ScanService.checkIfEanCodeExists(s, context);
                    JsonObject post = new JsonObject().get(response.body().toString()).getAsJsonObject();
                    if (post.get("items").getAsString().contains("ean")) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.logic , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    //DatabaseHandler itemsManager = new DatabaseHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
                    //itemsManager.addItem(response.body());
                    //adapter.setItemList(itemList);
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.not_in_database , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Vibrator vibrator;
                    vibrator = (Vibrator) mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vibrator.vibrate(3000);
                    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext.getApplicationContext(), notification);
                    r.play();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Item> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    public static void getPaletteItems(Context context, RecyclerviewAdapter adapterRecyclerView, String palNo,
                                       String basic) {

        //creating the paletteItemsApi interface
        ItemsApi itemsApi = retrofit.create(ItemsApi.class);

        //making the call object

        Call<List<Items>> call = itemsApi.getItems(palNo, basic);

        //call.execute();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Items>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Items>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Items>> response) {

                if(response.isSuccess()) {

                    List<Items> itemList = response.body();
                    adapterRecyclerView.setItemList((ArrayList<Items>) itemList);
                    adapterRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    int statusCode  = response.code();
                    Toast.makeText(context, statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }


            public void onFailure(Call<List<Items>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public AssetManager getAssets() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Resources getResources() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public PackageManager getPackageManager() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ContentResolver getContentResolver() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Looper getMainLooper() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTheme(int resid) {

    }

    @Override
    public Resources.Theme getTheme() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPackageName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getApplicationInfo() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPackageResourcePath() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPackageCodePath() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveSharedPreferencesFrom(Context sourceContext, String name) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteSharedPreferences(String name) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public FileInputStream openFileInput(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String name, int mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteFile(String name) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public File getFileStreamPath(String name) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public File getDataDir() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public File getFilesDir() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public File getNoBackupFilesDir() {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public File getExternalFilesDir(@Nullable String type) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public File[] getExternalFilesDirs(String type) {
        return new File[0];
    }

    @Override
    public File getObbDir() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public File[] getObbDirs() {
        return new File[0];
    }

    @Override
    public File getCacheDir() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public File getCodeCacheDir() {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public File getExternalCacheDir() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public File[] getExternalCacheDirs() {
        return new File[0];
    }

    @Override
    public File[] getExternalMediaDirs() {
        return new File[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String[] fileList() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public File getDir(String name, int mode) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, @Nullable DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveDatabaseFrom(Context sourceContext, String name) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteDatabase(String name) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public File getDatabasePath(String name) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] databaseList() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getWallpaper() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable peekWallpaper() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getWallpaperDesiredMinimumWidth() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getWallpaperDesiredMinimumHeight() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    public void setWallpaper(InputStream data) throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    public void clearWallpaper() throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent, @Nullable Bundle options) {

    }

    @Override
    public void startActivities(Intent[] intents) {

    }

    @Override
    public void startActivities(Intent[] intents, Bundle options) {

    }

    @Override
    public void startIntentSender(IntentSender intent, @Nullable Intent fillInIntent, int flagsMask, int flagsValues, int extraFlags) throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {

    }

    @Override
    public void startIntentSender(IntentSender intent, @Nullable Intent fillInIntent, int flagsMask, int flagsValues, int extraFlags, @Nullable Bundle options) throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendBroadcast(Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendBroadcast(Intent intent, @Nullable String receiverPermission) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent intent, @Nullable String receiverPermission) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendOrderedBroadcast(@NonNull Intent intent, @Nullable String receiverPermission, @Nullable BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver, @Nullable Handler scheduler, int initialCode, @Nullable String initialData, @Nullable Bundle initialExtras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user, @Nullable String receiverPermission) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendOrderedBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user, @Nullable String receiverPermission, BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver, @Nullable Handler scheduler, int initialCode, @Nullable String initialData, @Nullable Bundle initialExtras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendStickyBroadcast(Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendStickyOrderedBroadcast(Intent intent, BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver, @Nullable Handler scheduler, int initialCode, @Nullable String initialData, @Nullable Bundle initialExtras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void removeStickyBroadcast(Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendStickyBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendStickyOrderedBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user, BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver, @Nullable Handler scheduler, int initialCode, @Nullable String initialData, @Nullable Bundle initialExtras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void removeStickyBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, int flags) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, @Nullable String broadcastPermission, @Nullable Handler scheduler) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, @Nullable String broadcastPermission, @Nullable Handler scheduler, int flags) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ComponentName startService(Intent service) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ComponentName startForegroundService(Intent service) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent service) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean bindService(Intent service, @NonNull ServiceConnection conn, int flags) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void unbindService(@NonNull ServiceConnection conn) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean startInstrumentation(@NonNull ComponentName className, @Nullable String profileFile, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSystemService(@NonNull String name) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getSystemServiceName(@NonNull Class<?> serviceClass) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int checkPermission(@NonNull String permission, int pid, int uid) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int checkCallingPermission(@NonNull String permission) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int checkCallingOrSelfPermission(@NonNull String permission) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int checkSelfPermission(@NonNull String permission) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void enforcePermission(@NonNull String permission, int pid, int uid, @Nullable String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void enforceCallingPermission(@NonNull String permission, @Nullable String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(@NonNull String permission, @Nullable String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void grantUriPermission(String toPackage, Uri uri, int modeFlags) {

    }

    @Override
    public void revokeUriPermission(Uri uri, int modeFlags) {

    }

    @Override
    public void revokeUriPermission(String toPackage, Uri uri, int modeFlags) {

    }

    @Override
    public int checkUriPermission(Uri uri, int pid, int uid, int modeFlags) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int checkCallingUriPermission(Uri uri, int modeFlags) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int checkCallingOrSelfUriPermission(Uri uri, int modeFlags) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int checkUriPermission(@Nullable Uri uri, @Nullable String readPermission, @Nullable String writePermission, int pid, int uid, int modeFlags) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void enforceUriPermission(Uri uri, int pid, int uid, int modeFlags, String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void enforceCallingUriPermission(Uri uri, int modeFlags, String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void enforceCallingOrSelfUriPermission(Uri uri, int modeFlags, String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void enforceUriPermission(@Nullable Uri uri, @Nullable String readPermission, @Nullable String writePermission, int pid, int uid, int modeFlags, @Nullable String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public Context createPackageContext(String packageName, int flags) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Context createContextForSplit(String splitName) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Context createConfigurationContext(@NonNull Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Context createDisplayContext(@NonNull Display display) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Context createDeviceProtectedStorageContext() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDeviceProtectedStorage() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably failing in the static block and you are missing the error.  Try debugging and putting breakpoints at various points.

Comment: @YuriSchimke: I did and the reason why it fails is that in .client(okHttp), okHttp is null. It has to do with the passing of the context and the intialisation of the constructor for okHttp  here: static OkHttpClient okHttp;

    static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(PalletteApi.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttp)
            .build();

Comment: Debug this line and see where it sets the static value.  Also why is it static?

            okHttp = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(getSSLConfig(this).getSocketFactory())
                     .build();

The code is structured in a non typical way.

Comment: @YuriSchimke: Ok, I´ll look deeper into this, thanks so far!